# list indices must be integers or slices, not str while deleting nested key in dictionary

Tags: python

this reduced example show how I try to find and delete a nested key

```
sections = {}

def section_add(name, section):
    sections[name] = section
    return

def section_del(name, section):
    del sections[name][section]

one = {'one_1': ""}
two = {'two_1': '2','Bad': 'delete'}

section_add('one', one)
section_add('two', two)
section_del(['two']['Bad'])
```

the section_del method fails with

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

how would a function look like to delete a subkey value pair ?
The dictionary will be not even more nested however an iterative example to delete a nested key value pair would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
section_del(['two']['Bad'])
```

to

```
section_del('two', 'Bad')
```

Your function expects two plain positional arguments. What you attempt to do there

```
['two']['Bad']
# lst = ['two']
# lst['Bad']  # bound to fail
```

is to  access the element with key `'Bad'` from the singleton list `['two']` which of course makes little sense.

Comment: ha to simple thanks ! The values come from a list of key, value items so I have been starring at the wrong problem.